# Ajax enabled web shop

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create ajax based web shop(extjs for example).
It won't work on some mobile devices and users with js disabled in browsers.
That is probably about 5% of users. I would ignore users with javascript disabled but I can't ignore search engines. The most painful is that it won't be crawlable for search engines.
Google has some "complicated" rules how to achieve this for their search engine but this won't work for all other search engines.
So, i would like to know, what is the best approach to deal with this kind of problems?
Probably you have to create separate web sites, js enabled and js disabled web site?

And then with  tag in header on each page redirect all users with js disabled(or search engines) to no js web site.

This is a lot of pain. Are there some guidelines to achieve this with the least effort?
I'm also thinking to stay on pure html without any java script to avoid double web site programming. How do you deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise looking into progressive enhancement:
http://alistapart.com/article/progressiveenhancementwithjavascript

This means whilst the application will use AJAX for most users those that dont have javascript will simply see the page refresh instead of update instantly.

This does not mean you need to write the site twice, just means that you need to think about the JS and write in such a way it works on top of the original functionality.

This also means Web crawlers can find your content.

Answer (score 0):

You can create XML sitemaps for your product catalogue in your shop which are understood by all search engines: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Then, it doesn't matter if search engines can crawl your site or not.